# Installing Windows 7 upgrade adviser, get advpack.dll error

Tags: windows-xp, upgrade, 32-bit

I'm trying to install the Windows 7 upgrade advisor on an XP 32-bit laptop. When I run the program, I get a message that says:

"Error creating process... Reason: C:\Windows\system32\advpack.dll"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your installation of the .NET framework as far as I know. Additionally, What service pack of xp are you running?

I'd suggest running Windows updates, it will solve this issue for you by updating you to the latest SP and installing the newest .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on XP SP3, I would suggest upgrading to SP3 (with all due caution).

In any case, the windows 7 upgrade advisor system requirements specify at least XP SP2.